# Laravel Eloquent get data with closest to current date

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need help in fetching data which have the closest date concerning the current date,
Say, today is `2024-02-27`, and in the database, I have many rows with values(expiry) of 2024-03-28, 2024-02-29, and 2024-04-25. I need to pull rows which have the date `2024-02-29` and once this date passes on means on 2024-03-01, I get data only of 2024-03-28, not others,

I used the below code, but it gives all data,

```
   public function query(EodFuture $model): QueryBuilder
    {
        return $model->newQuery()->orderByRaw('ABS(DATEDIFF(expiry, \''.Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d').'\'))')->orderByDesc('last_trade_time');
    }
```

How to get data which have closest date to current date?

Comment: A simple approach would be to query for records that are equal to or before today, sort them, and return the first one. Would that work?

Comment: @TimLewis, almost. records which greater date than today then sort with first, and get all those records, removing next months date.

Comment: If you already know the date you can search that date, otherwise if you want to set a range in which the dates are good you can use *between*. I can't understand where is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're making this much more complicated than it needs to be: just order by date. You want only expiry dates for the current month? Use `where()` to limit the selection.

```php
public function query(EodFuture $model): QueryBuilder
{
    return $model
        ->whereBetween('expiry', [now()->startOfMonth(), now()->endOfMonth()])
        ->where('expiry', '>', now()) // assuming you only want future?
        ->orderBy('expiry')
        ->orderByDesc('last_trade_time');
}
```